# How to use $in operator with pair of attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider this collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "key" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "key" : 2,
    "b" : 5,
    "c" : 4
}

/* 3 */
{
    "key" : 3,
    "b" : 7,
    "c" : 9
}

/* 4 */
{
    "key" : 4,
    "b" : 7,
    "c" : 4
}

/* 5 */
{
    "key" : 5,
    "b" : 2,
    "c" : 9
}
```

I want to use the $in operator and write a query to return the document such (b, c) IN ((2, 3), (7, 9)). It means "return all rows where b is 2 and c is 3 at the same time, OR b is 7 and с is 9 at the same time."

How can I use $in operator to use multiple attribute values.

If I use the following query

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
    $and:[

           {b:{$in:[2,7]}},
           {c:{$in:[3,9]}}
         ]
    })
```

then I get following results

(2,3)

(7,9)

(2,9) --> This is unwanted record.

IN SQL world it is possible 
SELECT  *
FROM    demo
WHERE   (b, c) IN ((2, 3), (7, 9))

What is the equivalent in Mongo DB?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, the thing you are doing is getting all the pairs (2,3),(2,9),(7,3),(7,9).
But you want to match those one by one, so your valid pairs should be (2, 3), (7, 9). To satisfy this, you can match b and c one by one, pair them and "or" them after.

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
$or: [
       {$and: [ {b : 2}, {c : 3} ]},
       {$and: [ {b : 7}, {c : 9} ]}
     ]
})
```

Comment: I want to achieve this using $in operator, I think $and $or operation would not work  for large data. What if I have 10000 records.

Comment: @AtulSureka I do not think you should go with find() then, you may use aggregate() with grouping pairs as a new attribute and match accordingly with $in. I do not have any information about their performances, just trying to give you an idea.